# How to get the filenames of the samples from tensorflow dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

For example, I have the following code, which get me the image arrays and their labels:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

builder = tfds.ImageFolder('/home/ubuntu/X-dataset/')
ds_val = builder.as_dataset(split=['val'], shuffle_files=False, as_supervised=True)
ds_val = ds_val.batch(batch_size=32, drop_remainder=False)
ds_val = ds_val.map(lambda x, y: (process_test_data(x), y))
```

later on, I want to get all predictions from `ds_val` like this:

```
val_preds = model_classification.predict(ds_val, steps=len(ds_val))
```

to make comparisons with my ground truth table. However, I need some clue of the input sample names or paths, to attach them correctly on the GT table.

I wished something that shows me the order of the samples used during the dataset iteration like this:

```
ds_val.filenames
# ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', ..., 'filen.jpg']
```

I haven't seen anything on the `tfds` that allow me do this. My doubt are, Is there an tfds alternative for this?, and Is this a correct path to follow with tfds when measuring sets performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('image/*', shuffle=False)
for file in image_ds.take(3):
  print(file.numpy())
```

**Output**

```
b'image/flower.jpg'
b'image/flower2.jpg'
b'image/flower1.jpg'
```